# JSP - Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I am trying to make login with JSP with mvc architecture. I have the login form in index.jsp file and LoginController.java (servlet file) file in controllers package. I have done the URL mapping when I created the servlet file in the servlet creating steps. But when I run the tomcat server and after filling and submitted the login form I get this error. I am using Eclipse Oxygen IDE.

[image]
This is what I get in console

```
May 20, 2018 12:41:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11579 ms
May 20, 2018 12:41:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [LoginController] as unavailable
May 20, 2018 12:41:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [LoginController]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controllers.LoginController
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Login form

```
<form method="post" action="LoginController">
                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="password" id="inputloginPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
                </form><br>
```

LoginController.java file (servlet)

```
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LoginController() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    doPost(request,response);

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String userName = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean(); //creating object for LoginBean class, which is a normal java class, contains just setters and getters. Bean classes are efficiently used in java to access user information wherever required in the application.

    loginBean.setEmail(userName); //setting the username and password through the loginBean object then only you can get it in future.
     loginBean.setPassword(password);

    LoginQuery loginQuery = new LoginQuery(); //creating object for LoginDao. This class contains main logic of the application.

    String userValidate = loginQuery.LoginQuery(loginBean); //Calling authenticateUser function

    if(userValidate.equals("SUCCESS")) //If function returns success string then user will be rooted to Home page
     {
     request.setAttribute("userName", userName); //with setAttribute() you can define a "key" and value pair so that you can get it in future using getAttribute("key")
     request.getRequestDispatcher("/CustomerHome.jsp").forward(request, response);//RequestDispatcher is used to send the control to the invoked page.
     }
     else
     {
     request.setAttribute("errMessage", userValidate); //If authenticateUser() function returnsother than SUCCESS string it will be sent to Login page again. Here the error message returned from function has been stored in a errMessage key.
     request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);//forwarding the request
     }
}

}
```

web.xml file

[image]

folder structure

[image]

Comment: first of all your form's action parameter value should be `/LoginController`.. moreover according to naming conventions url should start with lowercase. Secondly your error clearly says your server's container is not able to find your servlet class.. clean build your project and remove compilation error shown in screenshot and try again

Comment: @Hiren I have tried everything you said but still no luck